Why is compute-sanitizer not reporting lineinfo like I've asked it too?
I have a CUDA C/C++ application that I wrote for an RTX2060, which I am now debugging. The first step that I took was to run the executable with compute-sanitizer, and discovered there were some out-of-bounds accesses occurring. Essentially, a very similar issue to the one happening in this thread: Unspecified launch failure on Memcpy. Here is what one looks like:
Starting iteration 0
Evolving fluid interior and boundary
========= Invalid __global__ read of size 4 bytes
=========     at FluidAdvance(float *, float *, float *, float *, float *, float *, float *, float *, const float *, const float *, const float *, const float *, const float *, const float *, const float *, const float *, float *, float *, float *, float *, float *, float *, float *, float *, float, float, float, float, float, int, int, int)+0xfc50
=========     by thread (0,2,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x74fafcffc110 is out of bounds
=========     and is 16,112 bytes before the nearest allocation at 0x74fafd000000 of size 1,048,576 bytes
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time

Using my novice understanding of CMake I had a working build system functioning, and in order to determine where the out of bounds accesses are occurring, I added the following line to CMakeLists.txt:
target_compile_options(imhd-debug PRIVATE $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:
                        -v
                        -g
                        -lineinfo
                        >)

However, when I rebuild the project, and run compute-sanitizer, I do not find any information added to the output that indicates the lines in the source where the errors are occurring.
Why is this, and what do I need to do to fix it? Thank you for any help.
EDIT: Question is solved! imhd-debug represented the main executable, but the function where the out of bounds access was occurring is defined in a different library that I needed to add a target_compile_options( ... -lineinfo) for. After doing this, I found the line information that I needed! :)

did you verify, via CMake verbose output, that the -lineinfo switch is actually present on the nvcc compile command line for the file/module in question?

As far as I can tell, the build is not actually calling nvcc, here is the output from the build: https://pastebin.com/uVxN1Yu5. There is $ fatbinary ... that includes the flag --generate-line-info

You should edit it into the question, not via external link.  This is essentially a CMake question , even though the title suggests that compute-sanitizer is somehow not behaving.  And you may have misinterpreted my suggestion about "CMake verbose".  I am not suggesting a CUDA verbose setting (which seems to be how you got to looking at fatbinary ...) but instead a CMake verbose output, so it will show you the command lines it is issuing rather than just a progress statement.

Thank you for the corrections. Yes, my lack of proper understanding about CMake is essentially the crux of the matter here, and I apologize for any misinterpretation on my end. I followed your advice, and added set( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on ) at the beginning of my CMakeLists.txt.
Consequentially, I realized that in CMakeLists.txt, I was failing to provide the -lineinfo option to the library where the function with the out-of-bounds access was occurring. After rectifying this, I am now seeing the line information that I need. Thank you very much for your help!

On Stackoverflow, its perfectly acceptable to answer your own question.  However you should not edit the answer into the question itself.  Instead, you should provide it as an answer (below).

EDIT: Question is solved! imhd-debug represented the main executable, but the function where the out of bounds access was occurring is defined in a different library that I needed to add a target_compile_options( ... -lineinfo) for. After doing this, I found the line information that I needed! :)
